# Solve for $+r$ ; $A=2\pi r^2+2\pi rh$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve for $+r$

$$A=2\pi r^2+2\pi rh$$ Since $2\pi$ is common on both sides of the $+$ so I will take it out
$$A=2\pi (r^2+rh)$$ 
Now, divide both sides by $2\pi$
$$\dfrac{A}{2\pi}=r^2+rh$$
Then, we can divide by the $h$
$$\dfrac{Ah}{2\pi}=r^2+r$$
Then; 
$$0=r^2+r-\dfrac{Ah}{2\pi}$$ 
Quadratic formula $=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ $a=1,b=1,c=?$ What are the values of $a,b,c$

Comment: I'm ultimately trying to isolate the variable $r$ in a positive form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a series of mistakes in your solution. I'll mark them one by one:

You correctly arrive to

$$\frac A {2\pi}=r^2+rh$$

But "dividing by $h$" produces

$$\frac 1 h \frac A {2\pi}=\frac 1 h\left(r^2+rh\right)$$

$$\frac 1 h \frac A {2\pi}=\frac {r^2} h+\frac{rh}h$$

$$\frac 1 h \frac A {2\pi}=\frac {r^2} h+r$$

So that step is wrong.

Similarily, if you have

$$\dfrac{Ah}{2\pi}=r^2+r$$

then "taking square roots" produces

$$\sqrt{\dfrac{Ah}{2\pi}}=\sqrt{r^2+r}$$

You then seem to assert

$$\sqrt{r^2+r}=2r$$

Let's check if it is indeed true for, say $r=1$, which gives

$$\sqrt{2}=2$$

which is manifestly false. So there is something awry there, too.

The best thing you can do is check wether each step is correct. To solve for $r$, since

$$\frac A {2\pi}=r^2+rh$$

is a quadratic we need to make a very old trick, which is called completing the square:

$$\eqalign{
  & \frac{A}{{2\pi }} = {r^2} + rh  \cr 
  & \frac{A}{{2\pi }} = {r^2} + 2r\frac{h}{2}  \cr 
  & \frac{A}{{2\pi }} = \underbrace {{r^2} + 2r\frac{h}{2} + {{\left( {\frac{h}{2}} \right)}^2}}_{{\text{This is a perfect square!}}} - {\left( {\frac{h}{2}} \right)^2}  \cr 
  & \frac{A}{{2\pi }} = {\left( {r + \frac{h}{2}} \right)^2} - {\left( {\frac{h}{2}} \right)^2}  \cr 
  & \frac{A}{{2\pi }} + {\left( {\frac{h}{2}} \right)^2} = {\left( {r + \frac{h}{2}} \right)^2}  \cr 
  & \sqrt {\frac{A}{{2\pi }} + {{\left( {\frac{h}{2}} \right)}^2}}  = {{{\left( {r + \frac{h}{2}} \right)}^2}}   \cr 
  & \pm \sqrt {\frac{A}{{2\pi }} + {{\left( {\frac{h}{2}} \right)}^2}}  =  {r + \frac{h}{2}}  \cr} $$

Note in the last steps we take the square root. We then have to think about both the positive and negative root. So you final solution is

$$r =  - \sqrt {\frac{A}{{2\pi }} + {{\left( {\frac{h}{2}} \right)}^2}}  - \frac{h}{2}{\text{ or }}r = \sqrt {\frac{A}{{2\pi }} + {{\left( {\frac{h}{2}} \right)}^2}}  - \frac{h}{2}$$

**COMPLETING THE SQUARE**:

Say we have a quadratic $$0=ax^2+bx+c$$

"Completing the square" consist of writing it in the form

$$0 = A{\left( {x + h} \right)^2} + C$$

We can accomplish this with some "trickery"

$$\eqalign{
  & 0 = a{x^2} + bx + c  \cr 
  & 0 = 4{a^2}{x^2} + 4abx + 4ac{\text{ ;  multiply by }}4a  \cr 
  & 0 = {\left( {2ax} \right)^2} + 2 \cdot \left( {2ax} \right) \cdot b + 4ac{\text{ ; cleverly rearrange the eqn}}{\text{.}}  \cr 
  & {b^2} = {\left( {2ax} \right)^2} + 2 \cdot \left( {2ax} \right) \cdot b + {b^2} + 4ac{\text{ ;  add }}{b^2}  \cr 
  & {b^2} = \underbrace {{{\left( {2ax} \right)}^2} + 2 \cdot \left( {2ax} \right) \cdot b + {b^2}}_{{\text{This is a perfect square!}}} + 4ac  \cr 
  & {b^2} = {\left( {2ax + b} \right)^2} + 4ac  \cr 
  & {b^2} - 4ac = {\left( {2ax + b} \right)^2}  \cr 
  & \sqrt {{b^2} - 4ac}  = 2ax + b  \cr 
  &  - b + \sqrt {{b^2} - 4ac}  = 2ax  \cr 
  & \frac{{ - b + \sqrt {{b^2} - 4ac} }}{{2a}} = x \cr} $$

Comment: I have forgotten exactly how completing the square works. I know it is a way of solving a quadratic equation. Do you think you could shed some light on that using $0=ax^2+bx+c$.

Comment: @AustinBroussard You could set $$0 = {r^2} + rh - \frac{A}{{2\pi }}$$ but you'll arrive to the same result and it will be a little more cumbersome, IMO.

Comment: Right, but could you sort of "teach" me completing the square again. It would help me grasp the concept of it for future problems.

Comment: @AustinBroussard Oh, sure.

Comment: Thanks for the extra help.

Comment: @AustinBroussard Anytime.

Comment: So, ultimately you come up with the quadratic formula?

Comment: @AustinBroussard TA-DA! Though the completing the square thing is basically steps 1-6.

Comment: Question: after examining this whole completing the square thing could this be possible: 
Quadratic form $$=ax^2+bx+c=0$$   
Completing the Square form:  
$$a(x+d)^2+e=0$$ where $$d=\frac{b}{2a}$$  $$e=c-\frac{b^2}{4a}$$ yields $$a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)=0$$

Comment: @AustinBroussard That is true.

Comment: So, plugging in the formula would make: $$1\left(rh+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(-\frac{A}{2\pi}-\frac{1}{4}\right)=0$$

Comment: @AustinBroussard Look again. Your $x$ is $r$, not $rh$.

Answer (score 2):

No! $\sqrt{r^2 + r} \neq 2r.$

What you have is a polynomial equation $r^2 + r - \dfrac{Ah}{\pi} = 0.$

Since this is a homework, I will only give a hint: the two roots $r_1, r_2$ of quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ are $$ r_{1,2} = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}{2a}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Try subtracting $2\pi r^2 + 2\pi rh$ from both sides of the original and completing the square. I can expand on this if you need me to.

Answer (score 2):

You've made two errors that I can spot first from here to here:

$$\dfrac{A}{2\pi}=r^2+rh$$

$$\dfrac{Ah}{2\pi}=r^2+r$$

Dividing by h doesn't work like that.

Your last square root is incorrect.  You should be looking at the problem in the form of:

$$0=r^2+r-\dfrac{Ah}{2\pi}$$

And then applying our friend the quadratic formula.